# Trying to use Arduino's HardwareSerial via Eclipse-AVR

Tags: c++, eclipse, arduino, avr

I am trying to port over the Hardware Serial library that now comes with the Arduino 1.0 IDE. I am compiling on a ATMega2560 processor and testing the Arduino USART library "HardwareSerial" with a simple "Hello World" example, but I am left with this strange sounding error.

It tells me that I am: `attempt[ing] to use poisoned "SIG_USART0_RECV"`... I have never heard of such an error before. I tried to find out what it was defined to and eclipse gave me this:

`#define SIG_USART0_RECV _VECTOR(25)` which was found in `iomxx0_1.h`.

Then from there `_VECTOR(n)` redirected to `__vector_25` via `#define _VECTOR(N) __vector_ ## N`. But those are in system paths, and I assume they are still valid since the current Arduino libraries still uses them.

Why would they poison their own defines? Do I need to declare something else before I try compiling the project?

---

**Edit:**

I found the poison in `iomxx0_1.h` stating: `#pragma GCC poison SIG_USART0_RECV`. So why would they poison this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SIG_xx interrupt vectors were deprecated several years ago. You can see an updated list at:

[AVR-GCC Manual Online-Interrupt Vectors](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__interrupts.html)